# How do I Send Data to All Threaded Clients in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, chat, serversocket

I am fairly new to Java, and I am trying to construct a very basic Java Relay server that sends messages from clients to all connected clients. I have figured out how to do threading to allow multiple connections, but I am having trouble figuring out how to echo an incoming message to ALL connected socket threads.

Here is my Main.java source:

http://pastebin.com/vVewfv3s

Here is my SocketThread.java source:

http://pastebin.com/yHA2BcUi

Basically, I want to know the easiest way with my current coding setup to be able to send an incoming message from one client to all of the other clients. I am currently using the Windows telnet client as the client working with this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trivial way is to keep a collection of clients, say as a map or set. To send a message to all clients, you traverse the linked list of clients and put a reference to the message on each client's send queue. You need to protect these structures with proper inter-thread synchronization, of course.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that. My knowledge of Java is pretty new, but I know the basics. I am more learning all of the functions and libraries now. Could you show me some code or examples of how to do what you were talking about? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Punch "multithreaded java server" into your favorite search engine. Then work on adding each client to a shared map or set.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a decent one at: http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/tutorial/socket_chat.pdf

Comment: @zgillis See my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115784/passing-a-parameter-to-all-running-threads/13116162#13116162 this should really work.